# Why is there no RuneWriter interface in Go's io package?

Tags: types, interface, go, io

[Go's `io` package](http://golang.org/pkg/io/) contains (among others) the following interfaces:

```
type ByteReader interface {
        ReadByte() (c byte, err error)
}

type ByteScanner interface {
        ByteReader
        UnreadByte() error
}

type ByteWriter interface {
        WriteByte(c byte) error
}

type RuneReader interface {
        ReadRune() (r rune, size int, err error)
}

type RuneScanner interface {
        RuneReader
        UnreadRune() error
}
```

But there is no `RuneWriter` interface:

```
type RuneWriter interface {
        WriteRune(r rune) (size int, err error)
}
```

Is there a reason that `RuneWriter` is missing?

Comment: If you need something like that then define it in your own code/package. In many places the standard packages only define what they use/need rather than a complete set. As far as I can tell, `bufio.Reader` is the only thing in the standard packages that would implement your `RuneWriter` (and `bufio.Reader` has many other methods that are also not a part of any interface).

Comment: @DaveC: But shouldn't they define what they expect users will need rather than just what they themselves need?

Comment: Not when that means guessing what any user anywhere might ever need. Interfaces are trivial to define as you need them. It would help nothing to have added `RuneWriter` to the io package.

Comment: As I said, if you have a place in your code where you'd like to call something like `WriteRune` you can either a) make your own interface and accept it as an argument or b) take an `io.Reader` argument and if a type assertion to your own interface fails then wrap it a `bufio.Reader`. Since bufio.Reader is the only thing in the standard packages that implements it (a) effectively just forces your callers to wrap in bufio.Reader (or their own version of something similar).

Comment: E.g. see stuff like [compress/flate.NewReader](https://golang.org/pkg/compress/flate/#NewReader) that does [just that](https://golang.org/src/compress/flate/inflate.go?s=15326:15399#L685).

Comment: @DaveC: Also, you're wrong about `bufio.Reader` being the only thing that implements it. `bytes.Buffer` also does. And those are the only things that implement `io.ByteWriter` as well. So why do they have `io.ByteWriter` but not `io.RuneWriter`?

Answer (score 4):

The Go authors define interfaces based on need. They do not define an interface for the purpose of filling out a grid of possible methods. This policy helps to keep the standard library small and simple.

I think they concluded that there's little need for the the RuneWriter interface because they didn't need it in the standard packages or other packages that they maintain.

There's been no demand for the interface outside of the Go team. There are no requests for the interface on the issue tracker, mail list, or the available recorded history for the irc channel.

The other interfaces referenced in the question are used in the standard packages or other packages that the Go authors maintain.

You can define the interface in your own package or code. This is a very useful feature that's somewhat unique to Go.

Comment: "The Go authors have not seen a need for the RuneWriter interface." Well that's my question: why did they not see a need? "It's not needed in the standard packages or in any of the subrepo packages that they maintain." But neither is ByteWriter.

Comment: Yes, I can define my own interface, but the beauty of having it in the standard library is that it makes third party libraries more compatible with each other than they would be if they all had to define their own.

Comment: But you don't have to use the same name for an interface to be compatible. I can do `type Foobar interface { Read([]byte) (int,error) }` and my Foobar interface fully inter-operates with `io.Reader` or anyone else's equivalent interface (e.g. I can make functions that take or return my interface and other can pass or assign to `io.Reader`). It's the method signature that is important not the interface itself.

Comment: ByteWriter is used in four or five locations in the standard library.

Comment: Again, see examples of places in the standard library where they define ad-hoc interfaces themselves (like the compress packages example I gave earlier). It would be pointless to "standardize" the set of such interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Just a small addition to Be Bop's answer:

Interfaces are useful to define generic functions. E.g. `func f(foo interface { Foo() })` states something like "I am function f and I'll do a proper job if you give me something I can Foo() with."

Now consider interfaces like `RuneScanner`. A `RuneScanner` provides nontrivial methods, especially `UnreadRune` which cannot be easily simulated by "lower level" stuff.

What would a `RuneWriter` interface be good for? Define a function `func g(rw RuneWriter)` which announces itself as "Give me something I can write runes to and I'll do my job!" ? But there is no real need as this can be simulated trivialy by standard means: Define it as `func g(r io.Writer)` and just use `fmt.Fprintf(r ...)` inside.
If you want to write runes you have to have the ability to write 1 to 6 (?) bytes anyway and that is what an `io.Writer` provides. So no need for a `RuneWriter`.

Would it make code more readable or safer by introducing a `RuneWriter`? Probably not: A function `func g(rw RuneWriter)` clearly states that it only wishes to write *runes* to its argument. That's nice but not a really helpful for writing better programs. A rune is 1 to 6 bytes and the only additional promise that `g` makes is "anything written to my argument will be a valid UTF-8 encoded stream".  This is a very shallow promise.